# android setText get text from strings + position

Tags: android, string, int, settext

I have a viewPager that get its text from the string.xml.

The plan is, depending on the position of ViewPager, it gets the text from strings, for example if the user is in page 3 it should get text from string name="page3".

Here is my beta code that is incorrect:

```
tv.setText(R.string.page + position);
```

Comment: try like this...`tv.setText(getString(R.string.page) + position);`

Comment: @CRUSADER Obviously that doesn't work, he wants the string's identifier to depend on the number, not the string itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a resource from its name by using `Resources.getIdentifier`, eg:

```
String name = "page" + position;
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string", getPackageName());
tv.setText(id);
```

Comment: Source to above - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29   :)